# How do you change and update a certain character in a String using label and a pickerview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift5

I have a UILabel currently displaying "0000" and a pickerView with 4 components. Each of the components would represent one of the 4 characters in the label. So component 1 would update the first "0" and the second component would update the second "0" ... and so on. I have managed to correctly change them using obj-c by simply updating the string as follows:

```
value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0%@%@%@",
```

but when it comes to Swift I'm stuck. I can get the characters from the String but not update the label. Here is my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var matchresult: mylabel!

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


      var value:String = "0000"

      var firstSelection:Int
      var secondSelction:Int
      var thirdSection:Int
      var forthSelection:Int

      firstSelection = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:0)
      secondSelction = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:1)
      thirdSection = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:2)
      forthSelection = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:3)


      //First row selected of first component in pickerview
        if  firstSelection == 0 {

       //Get first character in String 'value'
          if var char = value.character(at: 0) {

          print("I found \(char)")

        //Change the 1st character to 0
          char = "0"

          print("I changed after\(char)")

         //update only the first character in string 'value' with 0
         // ???
         mylabel.text = value         
          }


      //Second row selected of first component in pickerview
        } else if  (firstSelection == 1) {

      //Get first character in String 'value'
          if var char = value.character(at: 0) {

          print("I found \(char)")
      //Change the 1st character to 1
          char = "1"

          print("I changed after\(char)")

      //update only the first character in string 'value' with 1
     // ???

   mylabel.text = value

          }

      }
```

Any help would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

Rather than a string declare an array which holds the 4 selected values of the picker view

```
var selectedValues = ["0", "0", "0", "0"]
```

and assuming this is the data source

```
let numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
   return numbers[row]
}
```

in `didSelectRow` update the value at index, join the array to a string and display it

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectedValues[component] = numbers[row]
    matchresult.text = selectedValues.joined()
}
```

Comment: Yes!  that worked, think I was overthinking it. Thank you Vadian.

Comment: Actually I'm stuck again. For the 3rd component I want to insert decimal points in-between the first characters in the UIlabel text. Before I used `"%@.%@"` to insert the decimal between and ignoring the first and second characters

Comment: You can build the string with `"\(selectedValues[0])\(selectedValues[1]).\(selectedValues[2])\(selectedValues[3])"`